# Complete list of all vimrc configuration options?

Tags: unix, vim, editor

I'm not quite sure if stackoverflow is the correct site to post this on, but i dont see any other better fit for it when it comes to the stack exchange sites.

Vim has a lot of documentation, everything from free books to interactive learning, but there seems to be a piece missing, at least from what i can see.

Despite all the documentation im unable to find a *complete* list of all options that can be specified in a .vimrc file, does anyone know where this is documented ? It is not documented in :help vimrc or any other documentation ive seen, not even the free books ive looked at. The vim tricks wiki gives an intro like so many other pages on the web, but thats about it..no page or documentation seems to list all available options for the vimrc file. The man page doesnt even list a single option, only usage and command line options.

The books and other documentation are good at mentioning how to use vim but not how to configure the configuration file.

So, does someone know where i can find a complete list of all available options in the vimrc file ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`:help 'option'` will take you to the documentation of any `option`. All of those are contained in a single documentation file named `option.txt`.

Additionally, you can obtain a special report that shows all options, a short help, and the current values via

```
:options
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... even though i found it out myself just minutes before your post im giving you the correct answer because of the handy list with :options..that will probably be usefull :)

Comment: Also see :help option-list and :help index and :help function-list. But vimscript is Turing complete, so there literally *cannot* be a list of every possible configuration.

Comment: `:set all` will show you all the available `:set` options